# org-insert-link sometimes produces "wrong type argument: stringp, nil" after prolonged use of emacs

Tags: org-mode, debugging, org-link

It usually happens after a couple of days of use that <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> / `org-insert-link` inside .org files does not allow me to insert new links anymore.

What I want to do is interactively insert link description and URL. I usually don't work with stored links via <kbd>C-c l</kbd>. This time, though, I tried to store a link and see  if it fixes the problem. It doesn't. The debug output:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("^file:\\(.+\\)::" nil)
  #f(compiled-function (l) #<bytecode 0x411d16ed>)((nil ""))
  mapcar(#f(compiled-function (l) #<bytecode 0x411d16ed>) (("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/privat.org::*Brackweder Baugenossenschaft" "Brackweder Baugenossenschaft") (#("file:/tmp/test.txt::Hello" 20 25 (fontified t)) nil) ("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/privat.org::*Foci" "Foci") (#("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/dev.org::as" 32 34 (wrap-prefix #("        " 0 7 (face org-indent) 7 8 (face org-indent)) line-prefix #("        " 0 7 (face org-indent)) fontified t)) "transition to CalendarView framework") ("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/dev.org::*add app icon" "add app icon") (nil "") (nil "")))
  org-link-fontify-links-to-this-file()
  org-insert-link(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-insert-link nil)
  call-interactively(org-insert-link nil nil)
  command-execute(org-insert-link)
```

The value of `org-stored-links`:

```lisp
(("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/privat.org::*Brackweder Baugenossenschaft" "Brackweder Baugenossenschaft")
 (#("file:/tmp/test.txt::Hello" 20 25
    (fontified t))
   nil)
 ("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/privat.org::*Foci" "Foci")
 (#("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/dev.org::as" 32 34
    (wrap-prefix
     #("        " 0 7
       (face org-indent)
       7 8
       (face org-indent))
     line-prefix
     #("        " 0 7
       (face org-indent))
     fontified t))
   "transition to CalendarView framework")
 ("file:~/Pending/org/gtd/dev.org::*add app icon" "add app icon")
 (nil #1="")
 (nil #1#))
```

- `org-insert-link` works when the insertion point is inside an existing `[[...]]` link
- `org-insert-link` works interactively in non-.org file buffers

So:

1. Does the debug output indicate that passing the result of `mapcar` to `org-link-fontify-links-to-this-file()` returns `nil`?
2. Is there a value in my `org-stored-links` that is faulty? (How can I prevent this from happening?)

Comment: The `car` of each entry of `org-stored-links` must be a string (the link target). That follows from the first `mapcar` in `org-link-fontify-links-to-this-file`. Therefore the last two entries of your `org-stored-links` are invalid. Configuration: Emacs 26.1 with org-mode 9.1.13. Pitingly your tracing is too late. It is important to detect when the invalid entries are stored in `org-stored-links`. Since these are the last two items and the links are stored with `push` it must happen at the beginning of your session. You can give `org-store-link` an `:after`-advice and check `org-stored-links`.

Comment: Note that org also pushes links on `org-stored-links` in function `org-protocol-store-link`. So you should also put an `:after`-advice on that function with a check that signals a `user-error` if there is thrash on `org-stored-links`. If you activate debug-on-error you also get a backtrace.